# How to stream logs to Google Cloud Storage bucket like Google Cloud Build

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, stream, google-cloud-storage

I would like to 'live stream' the content of some log files on some Google Cloud machines to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, but it is not obvious to me how I would tackle this.

Result should be similar to the logs of Google Cloud Build, available while they are being produced.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're wanting to do, Stackdriver and it's monitoring built-in might do what you want (sorry, it's called Operations now) https://cloud.google.com/products/operations.

If not, and you really want it to go to GCS or something similar (although depending again on what you want, marshaling the logs into more structured data and putting it into a database might make more sense) the best way IMO would be to send logs to a local file, and on a timer, or on a system watcher that looks to the size of the log, etc, rotates the log and uploads the file to GCS. I've done things like this using a cron job and a shell script that uses gsutil (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to upload the file to GCS, then delete it locally.

Edit: Sorry, saw that you want it available "live"... this is a bit harder, but I would implement something like I described where logs write out to a DB like Cloud SQL in that case. I don't think GCS is the right tool for a "live" log situation like that. If you can't get what you need out of Stackdriver (and there are these things called sinks that you can write which parses Stackdriver into db options if you look in there) then writing directly to a database is probably your best bet. Cloud SQL is very low latency, so would be highly available for other processes to work with. If you want a NoSQL approach instead, BigTable or Firestore are good options.